# How to validate Mailchimp api key in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I want to validate my mailchimp apikey if user enter wrong api key the message or exception should be shown that wrong mailchimp api:

My Code is:

```
                 public function authenticateApiKey(Request 
                 $request)
{
    $fieldsValidation = [

        'api_key' => 'required|unique:apikey,api_key',

    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $fieldsValidation);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $resultArray = [
            'status' => 0,
            'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
            'dataArray' => []
        ];
    } else {
        $api = new APIKEY($request->all());

        $request->user()->apikey()->save($api);
        $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Mailchimp Api key added into system successfully!', 'dataArray' => $api];
    }
    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json($resultArray, 200);
}
```

I am saving my api key based on logged in user and in this code the api key is not validating.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a table named `apikey` with a column named `api_key`, is that correct?

Comment: yes my column name is api_key

Comment: Ok, and a table named `apikey`? That's what you're validation rule is saying at least.

Comment: yes my table name is apikey and column name is api_key

Comment: I am allowing here to enter any mailchimp apikey and thats not allowed any way can u please identify the solution of this problem.

Comment: Trying to thats why I'm asking questions. What does your validation message say when it fails?

Comment: {
    "status": 0,
    "message": "The api key has already been taken.",
    "dataArray": []
}

Comment: seems your api_key alreday exists!!

Comment: That's coming from MailChimp isn't it? Or is that the Laravel validation message?

Comment: Thats the message is display when i try to enter same api key twice but that also the requirement but the main issue is the api key should check on mailchimp account if api key is 123456 on mailchimp account and if i enter 123 its allowing here to enter thats not what i want. it should display the error that api key is not valid/not match with mailchimp account

Comment: its laravel validation message its not coming from mailchimp thats what i want it should check from mailchimp

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
else {
        $api = new APIKEY($request->all());
        $mailchimp = new \Mailchimp( $api);

       $mailchimp_ping = ($mailchimp->call('helper/ping'));

       if(!$mailchimp_ping){
            //key did not work
            //do stuff
       }

        $request->user()->apikey()->save($api);
        $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Mailchimp Api key added into system successfully!', 'dataArray' => $api];
    }
```

The above `call` will return false if API key is not valid and in case of a valid key it will return something like:

```
array(1) { ["msg"]=> string(20) "Everything's Chimpy!" }
```

Comment: Method "call" is not supported. its saying this

Comment: $Sapnesh Nail if i copy exact code of ur its saying  Class 'Mailchimp' not found

Comment: Can u please help me?

Comment: @syed1234 I am sorry I have no idea why it does not work but the basic idea is to make a request using the api key. If there is an error catch it and throw key invalid exception( just a message).

Comment: Can u please update me actually how to make a request using apikey

Comment: i have seacrch alot and other one is also saying make a request (/3.0/helper/ping) but no idea how to use. can u please guide me about it